# Eclipse 4.3 Installlation of graphiti 0.9.2 from command line

Tags: eclipse, command-line

We were trying to install the Eclipse Feature "graphiti" via command line. For this we used the [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.9.2/).

From the commandline we installed the available Feature Groups with the command:

```
eclipsec.exe
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.9.2 -installIU org.eclipse.graphiti.export.feature.feature.group -destination C:/JDT/4.3b/eclipse -profile DefaultProfile -followReferences
```

Unfortunately the mentioned command gives an error due to a dependency:

> !MESSAGE Missing requirement: Graphiti SVG Export (Incubation)
>   0.9.2.v20130211-0913 (org.eclipse.graphiti.export.batik 0.9.2.v20130211-0913) requires 'bundle org.apache.batik.dom [1.6.0,1.7.0)' but it could not be found

Any idea where to find the update site for org.apache.batik.dom feature?

Or do you have an idea how to automatic download dependent bundles?

Thanks for a hint.

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find these bundles in the Orbit project: http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/

Just select a version that is close to your Eclipse release (for 4.3, the [latest release](http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140114142710/) should be fine).

To make Eclipse download it automatically, you need to add the update site (the p2 links are at the top of the Orbit Build pages).

[standaloneUpdate supports the command addSite](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html) and it should allow you to pass a URL (the documentation says it needs a local folder). If that doesn't work, you need to run Eclipse once and add the p2 repo URL manually in the install dialog or the preferences.

Comment: If this solved your problem, then please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)